# SUMIF or SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, sum

I am trying populate H3 with the sum of column E for rows that have the same month and same year as H2. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working formula without another column:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$2:$A$6)=MONTH(H$2))*(YEAR($A$2:$A$6)=YEAR(H$2))*$E$2:$E$6)
```

And the french version:

```
=SOMMEPROD(--(MOIS($A$2:$A$6)=MOIS(H$2))*--(ANNEE($A$2:$A$6)=ANNEE(H$2))*$E$2:$E$6)
```

This is an array formula you have to validate with Ctr + Shift + Enter

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. Do you have a link to a tutorial?

Comment: I don't think there is any specific tutorial for this kind of issue. I'd say to improve your ease with Excel formulas is to practice. Yet, you can very often find inspiration with Google

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very elegant, but does the trick.

1. Add a new column that will calculate the month and year from the date to the left of Date.
2. Add the same formula in row 1 above the totals (H1, I1, J1, etc)
3. Set the sumif formulas to use these calculations to find the intersection

The MonthYear formula: `=TEXT((B3),"mmm") & " " & TEXT((B3),"yyyy")`

The sumif formula: `=SUMIF(A3:A6, E2, C3:C6)`

Here's my spreadsheet with the new column and row headers added:
[image]

And here are the formulas (CTRL+~):
[image]

Comment: This works too, thanks. However, I want to limit the additional columns.